# How To Generate Circular Library In Angular

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular11

I have an issue to generate a circular library.

**For an example:** I have 2 library, the first one is *@core/entity* and the second one is *@core/model*.

In my entity, I have 2 entity, that is `UserEntity` and `OrganizationEntity`

**UserEntity:**

```js
import { OrganizationModel } from '@core/model';

export class UserEntity {
    organization: OrganizationModel;
}
```

**OrganizationEntity:**

```js
export class OrganizationEntity {
   code: string;
   name: string;
}
```

And in my model, I have 2 model, that is `UserModel` and `OrganizationModel`

**UserModel**

```js
import { UserEntity } from '@core/entity';

export class UserModel extends UserEntity { }
```

**OrganizationModel**

```js
import { OrganizationEntity } from '@core/entity';

export class OrganizationModel extends OrganizationEntity { }
```

My problem is, when I build my *entity* library, angular will remove all of them in my dist directory and it will make the `UserEntity` will be error, it's because `UserEntity` lookup the `OrganizationModel` and then `OrganizationModel` lookup the `OrganizationEntity` ("Organization Entity is doesn't exists anymore, because it's temporarily re-generated").

I need your help, how to fix this code in this situation, thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can do much, also I think there is something wrong with your architecture if these things happen ... just merge the two libraries together.

Comment: Yeah, ofcourse I merge it, but I need to know, maybe someone know how to fix that's problem. Or maybe angular team can upgrade they code, so when some package re-build, it's never remove existing until the build complete ("maybe later").

Comment: The code as posted is not circular. `UserEntity` imports `OrganizationModel` which extends `OrganizationEntity` which is a ordinary structure. It is unclear when the error is generated. It seems that some other code is searching for an element which Angular eliminated because it seemed useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fast way to break a circular references is a third library that both point to it.

also maybe you can try to replace OrganizationModel -> OrganizationEntity in your UserEntity so no longer needs the other library.

And if your entity is only holding data, use interface instead of class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate it. I agree with the first one, first, I create an Entity Library and publish on npm and then I create Model and I publish it to npm. After that, I back to my entity and add that Model and it's working. But the second options I don't think so, because this is a big project so we can't change the base.